# How to read a property file in angularjs config block to do environment related configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i want to read a property file from resources/environmet.properties,So that i can do environment related configuration in my config block.

```
angular.module('app').config(function($logProvider) {
read the ENV variable from environmet.properties if its DEV Environment 
enable logging
$logProvider.debugEnabled(ENV === 'dev');
```

I tried to inject $http service or my custom service to read the properties file from resources/environmet.properties but i am getting error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $http
```

i dont want to use the constant provided by angularjs

```
angular.module('app').constant("myConfig", {
"url": "http://localhost",
"ENV": "prod"
 })
```

and i also dont want to use grunt's grunt-ng-constant, So how can i achieve this using a simple property file

Comment: If u want store such settings in file create .json one

Comment: In that file i am storing data in json format , but how can i access that  file in my config block through a server call